# I need to implement below logic through one sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master_table with a column Tel_num. Tel_num is 11 digits data like 02365785431. Now I have to take take the min as start_num and max as end_num when the numbers are in sequence and also populate its associated line_value.
If below things come up:

```
Tel_num    Line_value
023158100001   V1
023158100002   V1
023158100003   V1
023158100004   V1 
023158115645   V2
023158111546   V2
023158111547   V2
023158111617   V2
023158121110   V3
023158121111   V3
```

Then I want the numbers like

```
Start_NUM                    End_NUM         Line_Value
023158100001                023158100004        V1
023158115645                023158111547        V2
023158111617                023158111617        V2
023158121110                023158121111        V3
```

Can someone help please???

Comment: I don't think I 100% understand your question, would you care to elaborate a bit further? How are there 2 V2 Line_Values in your expected output from the above written logic? That's mainly what knocked me off the question as in terms of what you actually mean.

Comment: @Abir . . . According to your description of the problem, `023158115645` should be in a group by itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of groups-and-islands problem.  Here is a solution using the difference between the number and a row number

```
select line_value, min(tel_num), max(tel_num)
from (select t.*,
             ( cast(tel_num as number) -
               row_number() over (partition by line_value order by tel_num)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by line_value, grp;
```

This works because subtracting an increasing sequence from the `tel_num` values returns a constant value, when the `tel_num` values are sequential.

[Here](http://rextester.com/QKE65194) is a rextester.  Note that the results are different from those specified in the question because 023158115645 should not be combined with any other numbers.

Comment: . . . You also need other group.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . What other group?

Comment: By this way, your query would produce 3 rows for `Line_Value` v2 as because of difference.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . which is correct according to the *description* of the problem.  The OP does not seem to have the correct result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to use cumulative approach :

```
select line_value, min(Tel_num), max(Tel_num)
from (select t.*, sum(case when grp > 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by line_value, grp order by Tel_num) as grp1
      from (select t.*, coalesce(cast(Tel_num as number) - lag(Tel_num) over (partition by line_value order by Tel_num), 1) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by line_value, grp1;
```

EDIT : It seems you want only grouping for constituent `Tel_num`s if so, then you need only one grouping :

```
select line_value, min(Tel_num), max(Tel_num)
from (select t.*, coalesce(cast(Tel_num as number) - lag(Tel_num) over (partition by line_value order by Tel_num), 1) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by line_value, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE number (vnum varchar(20), number numeric);

INSERT INTO number (vnum, number)
  SELECT 'v1', 023158100001 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', 023158100002 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', 023158100003 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', 023158100004 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'v2', 023158115645  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', 023158111546  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', 023158111547  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', 023158111617  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', 023158121110  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', 023158121111  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', 023158121112;

SELECT min(number), start_num, max(number), end_num, vnum line_value FROM number GROUP BY vnum;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a couple of problems with your query - there should be no commas between the column and its alias, e.g. `min(number), start_num` should be `min(number) start_num`, but more importantly, your query won't work as the OP wants; all the V2 rows (ignoring the lower-case typo) would end up in one group, but there should be three rows for V2 in the output, since not all of the numbers are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE master_table ( line_value, tel_num ) AS
  SELECT 'V1', '023158100001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', '023158100002' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', '023158100003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V1', '023158100004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', '023158115645' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', '023158111546' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', '023158111547' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V2', '023158111617' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', '023158121110' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', '023158121111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'V3', '023158121112' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( tel_num ) AS start_num,
       tel_num AS end_num,
       line_value
FROM   master_table m
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   master_table p
         WHERE  m.line_value = p.line_value
         AND    TO_NUMBER( m.tel_num ) - 1 = TO_NUMBER( p.tel_num )
       )
CONNECT BY PRIOR line_value = line_value
AND    PRIOR TO_NUMBER( m.tel_num ) + 1 = TO_NUMBER( m.tel_num )
ORDER BY line_value, start_num;
```

**Output**:

```
START_NUM    END_NUM      LINE_VALUE
------------ ------------ ----------
023158100001 023158100004 V1
023158111546 023158111547 V2
023158111617 023158111617 V2
023158115645 023158115645 V2
023158121110 023158121112 V3
```

Comment: it is taking infinite time

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports Common Table Expressions (CTEs) so you could do this:

```
with ranked as (
    select Line_Value, Tel_Num, 
        row_number() over (partition by Line_value order by Tel_Num) as rowNum
    from master_table
)
, lastRow as (
    select Line_Value, max(rowNum) as lastRow
    from ranked
    group by Line_Value
)
select fn.Tel_Num, ln.Tel_Num, fn.Line_Value
from ranked fn
inner join ranked ln on fn.Line_Value = ln.Line_value
inner join lastRow lr on ln.Line_Value = lr.Line_Value and ln.rowNum = lr.lastRow
where fn.rowNum = 1
order by fn.Line_Value
```

Explanation:

- sort the Tel_Nums, ascending order, for each Line_Value, and assign them a row number
- find the last rowNum value for each Line_Value
- the final output will be a composite of these

  - ranked, where rowNum = 1, will give you the first Tel_Num for that Line_Value

    - I aliased that as fn for First Number
  - ranked, joined to lastRow, will give you the last Tel_Num for that Line_Value

    - I aliased that as ln for Last Number
- you need to join all of these by Line_Value so that we will get one output row per Line_Value
- you want it sorted by Line_Value

Comment: fixed a couple typos.  try it now.